# How to make a single executable file on Linux for distribution?

Tags: linux, bash

what I intend to do is:

1. distribute a bunch of jars to certain folders;
2. modify several existing config files.

Is it possible to create a single .bin file, which contains all jar files in task 1 and the script for task 2?  So when run this .bin file, it will finish task a and b in a batch.

Comment: yes ... what have you tried

Comment: I've found several posts talking about using red hat Linux tool which is not an option to me.

Comment: I don't mind negative rating but hate no response at all. I had experienced seven cowards giving me -1 without pointing to me even why they thought the question is stupid or non-sense. Appreciate for your response anyway.

Comment: Just see the reply, and I didn't vote you down. My feeling is, people vote you down is because there is no efforts from your questions. If you  can update your question with what you did and what problem you faced, not just waiting for the answers , others will be happy to help you.

Comment: @BMW Thanks for your inputs. Hope this is the reason. I will try to improve my posts though I'm reluctant to share my immature attempts...

Comment: ok. I think makeself could be the answer. Still trying how much I can go with the start-up script.

Comment: Your question seems specific to Java (because of `.jar` files), so needs some *Java* tag. Did you consider packaging your application (e.g. in `.deb` files for Debian and derivatives)?

Answer (score 1):

makeself is the answer. Download it from http://megastep.org/makeself/

Comment: If you want to refer steps to create **Makeself** then refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59211187/how-create-makeself-self-executable-archive-file-in-linux