# How create Makeself self executable archive file in LINUX? What is the steps to create Makeself self executable file in any Operating System?

Tags: linux, bash, compression, executable, archive

I want to create a self-executable archive using Makeself.
I referred to **[makeself.io](https://makeself.io/)** but didn't understand anything from it.
What are the steps for making a Makeself self-executable archive?

If I run this executable on any operating system then it should be work and do my required task.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/self-extracting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I am giving example of **archiving UBUNTU ISO** in **self executable archive.** (This is only for understanding)

1.First **download makeself** into your machine.

```
apt install makeself 

              OR
```

You could **download makeself** from **official website** *[Or Press here](https://github.com/megastep/makeself/releases/download/release-2.4.0/makeself-2.4.0.run)*
Then you will get file names as **makeself-2.4.0.run**.
Simply run this file by `./makeself-2.4.0.run` .
It will automatically create one directory named as **makeself-2.4.0**.

- Inside that directory you get ***makeself.sh*** script. This is your directly executable script.
  **You can use this file** instead of <s>**apt install makeself**</s>.

2.Then **create a directory** which you want to archive .

```
mkdir ISO
```

3.Then **copy** your **ISO file** in this directory.

```
cp <Source Path> <Destination Path>  // Here destination path is ISO
```

4.Then **create a script** named as *copy.sh*

```
vim Copy.sh
```

Inside this script write what you want to do with this ISO.
SO I want to copy this ISO into my /home/Downloads folder. So I write in script

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -r <filename> /home/Downloads
echo "File Copied Successfully"

##// Remember This script will automatically run after extracting this folder //
```

Give permssion to script

```
chmod 777 Copy.sh
```

then

```
cd ..
```

So now you have 1 ISO directory and in that directory 1 ISO(UBUNTU iso) file and 1 script(Copy.sh).

5.Now run this command

```
makeself --pbzip2 ISO Copy_ISO.run "Copying ISO File" ./Copy.sh
```

here,

- pbzip2 --- Use pbzip2 instead of gzip for better and faster compression on machines having 
       multiple CPUs. (you can use any zipping algorithm mentioned in [here](https://makeself.io/))
- ISO --- It is the name of the directory that contains the files to be archived
- Copy_ISO.run --- It is the name of the archive to be created
- "Copying ISO File" --- It is an arbitrary text string describing the package. It will be 
                      displayed while extracting the files.
- ./Copy.sh --- It is startup_script. It is the command to be executed from within the directory 
            of extracted files.

It will generate **Copy_ISO.run** file.

So you can **run** this **Copy_ISO.run** file on ***any system***.

6.Command to run is -->

```
./Copy_ISO.run
```

This will **copy** your *UBUNTU ISO* file in ***/home/*** directory. You can run this script on any system. You don't need to carry another zip file of UBUNTU ISO.